# Maximizing a nonlinear eigenvalue equation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:
I need to find a $2\times 2$ self-adjoint matrix $B$ that maximizes the real number $x$ subject to the following non-linear eigenvalue problem:
$$f(B)=x B$$
Here $f$ is a non-linear function.
$B$ can be parametrized in terms of Pauli matrices: $B = \frac{1}{2}(I+r_x\sigma_x+r_y\sigma_y+r_z\sigma_z)$ in terms of 3 real numbers $(r_x,r_y,r_z)$.
One problem is that $B$ is not even necessarily invertible, so I do not even know how to solve for $x$, let alone maximize it.